# Vertical link in page sides

Tags: html, css

How can I have links in my pages sides like places i colored in image below and move as page scrolls (fixed position)?

[image: sample]

Comment: For this purpose, You have to use iframe property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that amount of information I can give you this much of an answer

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="aside-fixed aside-left">left</a>
<a href="#" class="aside-fixed aside-right">right</a>
```

CSS

```
.aside-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.aside-left {
    left: 0;
}
.aside-right {
    right: 0;
}
```